# Converting JavaScript code to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I need help converting this code to PHP.

```
var formula = [10,6.7,3.4];  
var user1 = [1,0,2,1,1,0,2,2,2,2];  
var user2 = [2,1,2,0,1,2,2,2,0,0];  
var result = 0;  
calculate();  
function calculate(){  
    for(var i=0; i<user1.length; i++){  
        result +=formula[Math.abs(user1[i]-user2[i])]  
    }
}  
alert(result);
```

PHP code:

```
<?php     
$formula = array(10,6.7,3.4);  
$user1 = array(1,0,2,1,1,0,2,2,2,2);  
$user2 = array(2,1,2,0,1,2,2,2,0,0);  
$result = 0;  
function calculate(){  
    for($i=0, $size = count($user1); $i<$size; $i++){  
        $result += $formula(abs($user1[$i]-$user2[$i]));  
    }
}
calculate();  
echo $result;  
?>
```

PHP code does not work. Help me please.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Answer (score 6):

The variables `$user1, $user2, $formula` are not in scope - Pass them to the function:

```
function calculate( $user1, $user2, $formula) {  
    $result = 0;
    for( $i = 0, $size = count($user1); $i<$size; $i++){  
        $result += $formula[ abs( $user1[$i]-$user2[$i]) ]; 
    }
    return $result;
}  
$result = calculate( $user1, $user2, $formula);  
echo $result;
```

Also, you're missing the indexing on the `$formula` array, I've added it above.

```
        $result += $formula[ abs( $user1[$i]-$user2[$i]) ];
```

Finally, I've added `return $result;` to the function that returns the computed value.

Comment: Also, he dropped the formula lookup inside the for loop.

Comment: You should also `return $result`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I've added both of your suggestions and initialized `$result` to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass variables along and return the result.

```
$formula = array(10,6.7,3.4);  
$user1 = array(1,0,2,1,1,0,2,2,2,2);  
$user2 = array(2,1,2,0,1,2,2,2,0,0);  

function calculate($user1, $user2, $formula){  
    for($i=0, $size = count($user1); $i<$size; $i++){  
        $result += $formula[abs($user1[$i]-$user2[$i])];  
    }
    return $result;
}  
$result = calculate($user1, $user2, $formula);  
echo $result;
```

Comment: You forgot the `return`, I added it for ya :-P